# getAccessibilityButtonController Android Accessibility Service

Tags: android

I have been looking at the new methods available for Accessibility in Android O. I ran across this new method called  getAccessibilityButtonController, I am unsure precisely what it does and an intended use. I know that in Android O there is a navigation button that can be used for an accessibility service. Does this accessibility button only launch the accessibility service, or could it have other functionality within the service such as to do specific tasks? I am curious possible uses for the accessibility and the  getAccessibilityButtonController methods. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can do pretty much anything you want it to. From the [android accessibility doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#button), the button allows you to register a callback that has an onClicked method. If you enable the button and provide said callback you can execute whatever you'd like in the context of that callback.

Edit: The android documentation has been updated so the following should no longer be necessary.

Note that if you read the doc there's currently an example that has a call to getAccessibilityButtonController() within onCreate(). This is incorrect because the controller isn't valid until onServiceConnected is called. I've modified the example below to show something that should work.

```
private AccessibilityButtonController mAccessibilityButtonController;
private AccessibilityButtonController
        .AccessibilityButtonCallback mAccessibilityButtonCallback;
private boolean mIsAccessibilityButtonAvailable;

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    mAccessibilityButtonController = getAccessibilityButtonController();
    mIsAccessibilityButtonAvailable =
            mAccessibilityButtonController.isAccessibilityButtonAvailable();

    if (!mIsAccessibilityButtonAvailable) {
        return;
    }

    AccessibilityServiceInfo serviceInfo = getServiceInfo();
    serviceInfo.flags
            |= AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_ACCESSIBILITY_BUTTON;
    setServiceInfo(serviceInfo);

    mAccessibilityButtonCallback =
        new AccessibilityButtonController.AccessibilityButtonCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onClicked(AccessibilityButtonController controller) {
                Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "Accessibility button pressed!");

                // Add custom logic for a service to react to the
                // accessibility button being pressed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAvailabilityChanged(
              AccessibilityButtonController controller, boolean available) {
                if (controller.equals(mAccessibilityButtonController)) {
                    mIsAccessibilityButtonAvailable = available;
                }
            }
        };

    if (mAccessibilityButtonCallback != null) {
        mAccessibilityButtonController.registerAccessibilityButtonCallback(
                mAccessibilityButtonCallback, null);
    }
}
```